# How to download all images from a website (not webpage) using the terminal?

Tags: terminal, download, images

I want a command that I type a URL, for example photos.tumblr.com, and it download all photos on this site in a folder, but not only images of the site's homepage. This command need to download the images from all parts of the site, such as photos.tumblr.com/ph1/1.png / photos.tumblr.com/ph3/4.jpg.

**Please show me an example using this url: http://neverending-fairytale.tumblr.com/ and test it before answer the question**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wget` can do it:

```
wget -A.png,.jpg,.gif,.jpeg -e robots=off -m -k -nv -np -p \
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.0.0/10; Linux)" \
http://site.url/
```

The only problem can be in case site generates its content using javascript.

Comment: Note for people trying to do this with HTTPS: you might need `--no-check-certificate` to get it to connect.